# Ground reference for POE 48V

Tags: poe

We have POE 802.3af in our design. We are facing some issues with it as elaborated below.

1. We have connected an LED load to the connector end with a POE splitter. A splitter is used to convert 48V to 12V.  When the board power ON LED glows after a minute, there is some delay found when glowing delay.
2. What is the ground reference for PoE 48V (VC2+)? Refer to attached image.

[image]

Comment: There is no gnd as such for an endpoint as there is a bridge rectifier or equivalent to allow for swapped pairs. The delay might be due to the PoE power negotiation.

Answer (score 0):

1. The delay may come from the device itself. As @Kartman pointed out in their [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/622937/ground-reference-for-poe-48v#comment1645601_622937), the power negotiation may take time.
2. POE (802.3af or 802.3at) 48V is a floating (i.e. isolated) voltage. So there's no ground reference. From what I understand from your schematic VCC_48V_POS is referenced to VCC_48V_NEG.